# Numerical approximation using trapezoidal formula

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, homework

I have bumped into a problem, that I cannot solve.

I have to approximate the value of ln3 using a composite trapezoidal formula, so that the error should be within (10)^-3!

How can it be solved?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your attempts, any code you have, etc. and we will more than glad to help.

Comment: Is this a question about the *Mathematica* software, or instead a question about *mathematics*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [error for the trapezoidal rule is](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/trapezoidalrule/TrapezoidalRuleProof.pdf)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So in your case:

```
h0 = Max[h /.NSolve[(3 - 1)/12 MaxValue[{D[1/x,{x,2}], 1 <= x <= 3}, x] h^2 ==10^-6, h]]

(* 0.0017320508075688774`*)
```

So the number of points for `NIntegrate[ ]` is

```
1/h0
(* 577.35 *)
```

Evaluating  then:

```
NIntegrate[1/x, {x, 1, 3}, 
 Method -> {"TrapezoidalRule", "RombergQuadrature" -> False, 
             "SymbolicProcessing" -> False, "Points" -> 578}, MaxRecursion -> 0]

(* 1.0986125111601406` *)
```

And the real error is:

```
% - Log[3]

(* 2.2249203079915958`*^-7 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using the function `` NIntegrate`TrapezoidalRuleData `` and the slightly modified version of the function `IRuleEstimate` from [NIntegrate's advanced documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html).

This function estimates an integral for given abscissas, weights, and error weights:

```
IRuleEstimate[f_, {a_, b_}, {absc_, weights_, errweights_}] := 
  Module[{integral, 
    error}, {integral, 
     error} = (b - a) Total@
      MapThread[{f[#1] #2, f[#1] #3} &, {Rescale[absc, {0, 1}, {a, b}], 
        weights, errweights}];
   {integral, Abs[error]}];
```

These define an integrand function, an integration interval, and a tolerance:

```
f[x_] := 1/Sqrt[x] + Sin[x];
{a, b} = {1, Pi};
tol = 10^-3;
```

Iteration to find the points for which the integration error is below the specified tolerance:

```
res = NestWhile[
  Prepend[IRuleEstimate[f, {a, b}, 
     NIntegrate`TrapezoidalRuleData[#[[1]], $MachinePrecision]], #[[1]] + 
     1] &, {2, Indeterminate, Infinity}, #[[-1]] >= tol &]

(* {21, 3.08491084368649, 0.00089805872430} *)
```

The number of integration points used in the last applied Trapezoidal Rule is:

```
Length@First@NIntegrate`TrapezoidalRuleData[res[[1]], $MachinePrecision]

(* 41 *)
```

Verification with `Integrate` (if the integral can be computed exactly):

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
Abs[res[[2]] - %]

(* -1 + 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] + Cos[1] *)
(* 0.00029916399268 *)
```